# Is it legal to use a downloaded copy of a sports broadcast for development purposes?

Tags: united-states, copyright, criminal-law, online-piracy, sport

Alice downloads a copy of a college sports game from the internet.  She does not have explicit permission from the owner of the broadcast.  Alice sends the downloaded video to Bob.

Bob uses the downloaded sports game to create an algorithm.  This algorithm creates 100 highlights of the game, each of which are 10 seconds long.  This algorithm is part of a commercial product.

Is Bob breaking the law?

Comment: It seems like a sequence of 10-seconds clips of videos can be trivially put back together to produce the original recording (which is presumably protected by copyright), so redistributing this is almost certainly not OK without permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Legality of the snippets

#### Bob creates a derivative work by making the snippets

The broadcast is a work for copyright law and is owned by the company that broadcasted it (because they have a master copy!). Any snippet of it is a derivative work. Only the owner of a work has the right to make a derivative work. Neither Alice, nor Bob is the owner.

Bob would infringe on the owner's rights by making a derivative work. Even if there is no Alice, Bob is not allowed to cut up the broadcast without the owner of the broadcast's permission. For the law, it does not matter if Bob uses an automatic process or does it himself.

#### Exceptions?

Yes, there is an exception for [Fair Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) in the United States. For that affirmative defense, Bob would need to show under [17 U.S.C. § 107](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107):

> Notwithstanding the provisions of sections 17 U.S.C. § 106 and 17 U.S.C. § 106A, the fair use of a copyrighted work, including such use by reproduction in copies or phonorecords or by any other means specified by that section, **for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching** (including multiple copies for classroom use), **scholarship, or research**, is not an infringement of copyright. In determining whether the use made of a work in any particular case is a fair use the factors to be considered shall include:
>
> 1. **the purpose and character of the use**, including whether such use is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;
> 2. the **nature of the copyrighted work**;
> 3. the **amount and substantiality of the portion used** in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole; and
> 4. **the effect of the use upon the potential market** for or value of the copyrighted work.
>
> The fact that a work is unpublished shall not itself bar a finding of fair use if such finding is made upon consideration of all the above factors.

If Bob shares the snippets or shows them around, the analysis is problematic for Bob, as I see three factors being slanted against him heavily: the broadcast was commercial, his snippets are (allegedly) the *heart* of the work, and just watching the highlight reel could be seen to supplant the full work and ruin the potential market. Also, the highlight reel does not seem to be used for any of the fair use purposes.

If the snippets are just used as a test-case, and more importantly never shown to anyone, then this might fall under research, which would avail fair use provided the factors can be framed well for Bob.

### Legality of the software

Software that identifies "hot moments" for example based on the noise of the audio track or some other means has clearly a legal use. A rightsholder might use this software to pre-cut his work and then sift through about 10 minutes of snippets instead of sifting a 2-hour broadcast for the most impactful moments. That the software *can* be used illegally does not make the software itself illegal.

Compare this cutting software to the [BitTorrent protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent): A torrent is nothing but a Peer-to-peer method to share files. That in itself is legal and indeed is used by some software companies to distribute the load on their fileservers. However, many people use the software for illegal filesharing. That doesn't make the protocol illegal though.

Or even simpler: The software is a hammer. Using a hammer to smack in nails is legal. Using it to smack someone's head is assault.

The software also isn't a derivative work of its test cases, as long as those are not included in the final product.

Comment: The question appears to be about the software that creates snippets from a video stream, not the snippets created from the video stream.

Comment: @user253751 No, the question is clearly about the *use* of the software, not the existance of it. But for you: jsut because a software *can* be used for illegal things but there are many legal things to do with it doesn't make the use of the software in general illegal. Think filesharing: sharing a program you made from scratch is legal. Sharing the ISO for GTA VI isn't. But in general, Filesharing programs are legal. Many smaller MMOs offer their installs via torrents.

Comment: "Bob uses the downloaded sports game to create an algorithm". Nothing in the question says "Bob uses the algorithm to create snippets"

Comment: @user253751 huh... indeed, but the derivative work is the snippets, not the cutting software. In the process of making the software he does create the infringing material and uses infringing material. That does not implicate the software though, as it has legal uses.